# Change SC.say("hello") Alert window border colour

Tags: smartgwt

How to change the border color of SC.say() popup window in smartgwt.Do i have to create a custom window and specify all edge images to change border colour.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, according to me, you should use `com.smartgwt.client.widgets.Dialog,` if you want customized look or widgets in place of SC class. You can have all the properties that will make your dialog looks the same such as:

```
dialog.setIsModal(isModal);
dialog.setMessage(message);
dialog.setMessageStyle(messageStyle);
dialog.setIcon(icon);
dialog.setButtons(buttons);
dialog.setTitle(title);
```